# Dropping and recreating databases in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am experimenting and learning with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.
I have a database where I made many experiments. Now I would like to drop and recreate it.
So I extract the creation script from database, I delete it and I use the script to recreate it.
To my surprise, all the tables, keys etc are still there.
How do I drop the database, so that I can rebuild the database from scratch?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='yourDBname')
DROP DATABASE yourDBname

CREATE DATABASE yourDBname
```

Comment: You are right, my question was stupid.
In fact, the tables that I was continuing to see were actually created in the master database, rather than in my database.

Comment: This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 34):

+1 to AnandPhadke for his part of the code

This code will close all active connections to the database and then drop it

```
WHILE EXISTS(select NULL from sys.databases where name='YourDBName')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
    SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL,'') + 'Kill ' + Convert(varchar, SPId) + ';'
    FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
    WHERE DBId = DB_ID(N'YourDBName') AND SPId <> @@SPId
    EXEC(@SQL)
    DROP DATABASE [YourDBName]
END
GO

CREATE DATABASE YourDBName
GO
```

Answer (score 12):

SQL Server 2016 (and above) support one line and atomic(?) syntax `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS database_name`

REF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Requiring the DBName to be typed more than once is error prone, at some point it'll be executed with inconsistent entries and unintended consequences.

The answers from AnandPhadke or Pierre with variable support would be preferred for me.

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(50) = 'YourDatabaseName'
USE master
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name= @DBName)
EXEC('DROP DATABASE ' + @DBName)

EXEC('CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBName)
```

or

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(50) = 'YourDatabaseName'
WHILE EXISTS(select NULL from sys.databases where name = @DBName )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
    SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL,'') + 'Kill ' + Convert(varchar, SPId) + ';' FROM MASTER..SysProcesses WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@DBName) AND SPId <> @@SPId
    EXEC(@SQL)
    EXEC('DROP DATABASE ' + @DBName)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

> I extract the creation script from database

This extract the creation script for everything in the database (tables, keys etc). If you simply want to create an empty database, just run `CREATE DATABASE <dbname>`

Answer (score 0):

This works best for me:

```
if exists (select name from sys.databases where name='YourDBName')
alter database YourDBName set single_user with rollback immediate
go
if exists (select name from sys.databases where name='YourDBName')
drop database YourDBName
```

Comment: I believe you misjudged this answer, @KhanImranAli. This one tries to answer, although poorly. This should be moderated by voting, not by flagging and negative review.

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.