# Input Sanitation SQLAlchemy Drop Database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Currently, I have the following code for a function that takes in `database_name` as an argument to drop the database provided.

```
 44     conn = self.db_eng.connect()
 45     conn.execute(text('DROP DATABASE ":database_name"'), database_name=database_name)
 47     conn.close()
```

Unfortuantely, I get the following error:

```
*** ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, u'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"\'dbname\'"\' at line 1') [SQL: u'DROP DATABASE "%s"'] [parameters: ('dbname',)]
```

when I specify the `database_name` as `db_name`.

I use `text` as I want to do input sanitation to whatever function is doing the database dropping. Is there a better way to drop a database with the provided name?

Answer (score 0):

The response is quite clear, there is some wrong with your sql code, you can check the belowing links for more details

- [DROP DATABASE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx)
- [Dropping and recreating databases in Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364250/dropping-and-recreating-databases-in-microsoft-sql-server)